# pip - на vps не могу установить. Ошибка: 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, vps, pip

Когда делаю `pip install ...`

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/requests/
```

Каждый раз выходить эта ошибка
После пробовал `wget`, пишет `ERROR 403: SSL is required.`
То есть понял в чем проблема, только как ее решить

VPS

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

pip

`pip 9.0.1`

Comment: У меня такая же ошибка на машине с прокси, когда прокси не пропускает запросы

Comment: а как это исправить, просто новенький в этом, можешь подсказать?

Comment: Самому интересно, но думаю проблема может быть в `ERROR 403: SSL is required.`

Comment: Что за vps? Какая ОС? Какая версия pip?

Comment: исправил, добавил в начало

Answer (score 0):

Надо было отключить ipv6

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

Comment: А почему это помогло?

Comment: А на моем vps всё отлично работает и через ipv6. Так что действительно непонятно, почему это помогло